# $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] with nginx proxy server --> get rewritten page urls

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

I am using nginx as reverse proxy server (front-end server) + apache as back-end server.

I notice I could NOT get the rewritten url output in php (like www.example.com/something/page/) with $SERVER["HTTPHOST"].$SERVER["REQUESTURI"] in nginx but it works in apache.

Note: The nginx rewrite works fine in the url but the problem is the output in php code.

I am getting such un-rewritten urls like www.example.com/index.php?a=something&b=page with $SERVER["HTTPHOST"].$SERVER["REQUESTURI"]

Can someone please help if I am doing something wrong?

This is the proxy part of my nginx

```
location ~ \.php$ {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: You don't pass original request so how would PHP know it? Usually it's passed as `proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;`

Comment: another thing please. using nginx server as reserver proxy of apache2, where is the best place to place mod_rewrite? in nginx or apache?

Comment: It depends on many factors. One simple rule is, if rewrite rules already written in one of them, just keep them there.

Comment: I initially have apache server serving sites now I am adding nginx that will reverse proxy so I looking for the best combination in your opinion. In fact, all pages are simply mod rewritten so no statics pages at all